# Белая граница у тени в svg

Tags: html, css, svg

Проблема в отображении тени.

Как видно из примеров ниже, появляются белые места.

```css
.container,
.svg {
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
}

.svg {
  box-shadow: rgb(0, 0, 0) 0px 0px 8px 13px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg class="svg" style="border-radius: 7%;">
   <rect  x="6.4" y="6.4" width="115.2" height="115.2"  style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); fill: none; stroke-alignment: inside; stroke-width: 12.8" rx="7%" ry="7%"></rect>
    <g transform="scale(0.6) translate(42.66666666666667, 42.66666666666667)"><style> #svg22 path, #svg22 circle, #svg22 polygon, #svg22 rect { fill: rgb(0, 0, 0) } #svg22 defs &gt; path { fill: none }  #svg22 path[fill="none"], #svg22 circle[fill="none"], #svg22 polygon[fill="none"], #svg22 rect[fill="none"] { fill: none } </style><style type="text/css"> #svg22 .st0{fill:rgb(0, 0, 0);} </style><path class="st0" d="M85.78,98.797l-9.157-74.312l1.803-15.536c0.091-0.793-0.161-1.586-0.689-2.181 c-0.531-0.595-1.29-0.934-2.086-0.934H52.35c-0.796,0-1.557,0.339-2.086,0.934c-0.53,0.595-0.78,1.388-0.689,2.181l1.803,15.536 L42.22,98.797c-0.103,0.822,0.167,1.648,0.736,2.254l19.008,20.235c0.528,0.562,1.265,0.879,2.036,0.879s1.508-0.317,2.034-0.879 l19.01-20.235C85.611,100.445,85.883,99.619,85.78,98.797z M72.566,23.098H55.434l-1.517-13.074h20.166L72.566,23.098z"></path></g>
      </svg>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<div class="container">
  <svg class="svg" style="border-radius: 50%;">
   <rect  x="6.4" y="6.4" width="115.2" height="115.2"  style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); fill: none; stroke-alignment: inside; stroke-width: 12.8" rx="50%" ry="50%"></rect>
    <g transform="scale(0.6) translate(42.66666666666667, 42.66666666666667)"><style> #svg22 path, #svg22 circle, #svg22 polygon, #svg22 rect { fill: rgb(0, 0, 0) } #svg22 defs &gt; path { fill: none }  #svg22 path[fill="none"], #svg22 circle[fill="none"], #svg22 polygon[fill="none"], #svg22 rect[fill="none"] { fill: none } </style><style type="text/css"> #svg22 .st0{fill:rgb(0, 0, 0);} </style><path class="st0" d="M85.78,98.797l-9.157-74.312l1.803-15.536c0.091-0.793-0.161-1.586-0.689-2.181 c-0.531-0.595-1.29-0.934-2.086-0.934H52.35c-0.796,0-1.557,0.339-2.086,0.934c-0.53,0.595-0.78,1.388-0.689,2.181l1.803,15.536 L42.22,98.797c-0.103,0.822,0.167,1.648,0.736,2.254l19.008,20.235c0.528,0.562,1.265,0.879,2.036,0.879s1.508-0.317,2.034-0.879 l19.01-20.235C85.611,100.445,85.883,99.619,85.78,98.797z M72.566,23.098H55.434l-1.517-13.074h20.166L72.566,23.098z"></path></g>
      </svg>
</div>
```

Пробовал добавить элемент с абсолютным позиционированием, который бы "закрашивал" белые места.

```css
.container,
.svg {
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
}
.container{
  position:relative;
}
.svg {
  box-shadow: rgb(0, 0, 0) 0px 0px 8px 13px;
}

.border{
  position: absolute;
  top:-1px;
  left:-1px;
  right:-1px;
  bottom:-1px;
  border:6px solid black;
  border-radius:7%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="border"></div> 
  <svg class="svg" style="border-radius: 7%;">
   <rect  x="6.4" y="6.4" width="115.2" height="115.2"  style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); fill: none; stroke-alignment: inside; stroke-width: 12.8" rx="7%" ry="7%"></rect>
    <g transform="scale(0.6) translate(42.66666666666667, 42.66666666666667)"><style> #svg22 path, #svg22 circle, #svg22 polygon, #svg22 rect { fill: rgb(0, 0, 0) } #svg22 defs &gt; path { fill: none }  #svg22 path[fill="none"], #svg22 circle[fill="none"], #svg22 polygon[fill="none"], #svg22 rect[fill="none"] { fill: none } </style><style type="text/css"> #svg22 .st0{fill:rgb(0, 0, 0);} </style><path class="st0" d="M85.78,98.797l-9.157-74.312l1.803-15.536c0.091-0.793-0.161-1.586-0.689-2.181 c-0.531-0.595-1.29-0.934-2.086-0.934H52.35c-0.796,0-1.557,0.339-2.086,0.934c-0.53,0.595-0.78,1.388-0.689,2.181l1.803,15.536 L42.22,98.797c-0.103,0.822,0.167,1.648,0.736,2.254l19.008,20.235c0.528,0.562,1.265,0.879,2.036,0.879s1.508-0.317,2.034-0.879 l19.01-20.235C85.611,100.445,85.883,99.619,85.78,98.797z M72.566,23.098H55.434l-1.517-13.074h20.166L72.566,23.098z"></path></g>
      </svg>
</div>
```

Проблема в том, что способ не универсальный. Может меняться радиус скругления, размер тени, положение тени. В некоторых случаях элемент `.border` выходит за границы - вылечить не удалось.

Вторая попытка была закрасить фон у `svg`.

```css
.container,
.svg {
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
}

.svg {
  box-shadow: rgb(0, 0, 0) 0px 0px 8px 13px;
  background: radial-gradient(at center center, rgb(255, 255, 255) 80%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 80%) black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="border"></div>
  <svg class="svg" style="border-radius: 7%;">
   <rect  x="6.4" y="6.4" width="115.2" height="115.2"  style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); fill: none; stroke-alignment: inside; stroke-width: 12.8" rx="7%" ry="7%"></rect>
    <g transform="scale(0.6) translate(42.66666666666667, 42.66666666666667)"><style> #svg22 path, #svg22 circle, #svg22 polygon, #svg22 rect { fill: rgb(0, 0, 0) } #svg22 defs &gt; path { fill: none }  #svg22 path[fill="none"], #svg22 circle[fill="none"], #svg22 polygon[fill="none"], #svg22 rect[fill="none"] { fill: none } </style><style type="text/css"> #svg22 .st0{fill:rgb(0, 0, 0);} </style><path class="st0" d="M85.78,98.797l-9.157-74.312l1.803-15.536c0.091-0.793-0.161-1.586-0.689-2.181 c-0.531-0.595-1.29-0.934-2.086-0.934H52.35c-0.796,0-1.557,0.339-2.086,0.934c-0.53,0.595-0.78,1.388-0.689,2.181l1.803,15.536 L42.22,98.797c-0.103,0.822,0.167,1.648,0.736,2.254l19.008,20.235c0.528,0.562,1.265,0.879,2.036,0.879s1.508-0.317,2.034-0.879 l19.01-20.235C85.611,100.445,85.883,99.619,85.78,98.797z M72.566,23.098H55.434l-1.517-13.074h20.166L72.566,23.098z"></path></g>
      </svg>
</div>
```

Появляется проблема с случаем, когда `border-radius: 0`. Также проблема с тем, что фон у `svg` должен быть прозрачным. А в этом случае он закрашивается.

Как можно решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Одна из проблем в том, что в svg линия утолщается и внутрь и наружу, при этом радиус скругления считается по середине этой линии. В `%` он вычисляется по другому,- от наружного размера.
При накладывании тени радиус скругления считается по наружной границе линии и размеры, так же по наружной.
То есть `7%` радиус в вашем SVG означает `0.07*(115.2+12.8)=8.96` и это будет соответствовать наружному радиусу - `8.96+(12.8/2)=15.36px`, а в процентах для тени это будет - `15.36/128=0,12`. То есть `12%`.
 Если не рассчитать радиусы то будут явные несоответствия в скруглении углов.

Но основная проблема в том, что скругление углов и наложение тени происходит неточно и по углам появляются пиксели фонового цвета. Эту проблему можно решить накладывая тень не на SVG а на отдельный блок на пиксель меньший по размеру.

Вот пример. Радиус скругления рассчитывается функцией `calc`. Думаю если доработать код, то параметры `7%`, `128px` и тп. можно задать переменными и менять только их.

```css
.container,
.svg {
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
}


.container {
  position:relative;
}

.shadow {
  position: absolute;
  left:1px;
  top:1px;
  width:calc(128px - 2px);
  height:calc(128px - 2px);
  border:none;
  box-shadow: rgb(0, 0, 0) 0px 0px 8px 13px;
  border-radius: calc((0.07*(115.2 + 12.8) + 12.8/2)*1px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="shadow"></div>
  <svg class="svg">
   <rect  x="6.4" y="6.4" width="115.2" height="115.2"  style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); fill: none; stroke-alignment: inside; stroke-width: 12.8" rx="7%" ry="7%"></rect>
    <g transform="scale(0.6) translate(42.66666666666667, 42.66666666666667)"><style> #svg22 path, #svg22 circle, #svg22 polygon, #svg22 rect { fill: rgb(0, 0, 0) } #svg22 defs &gt; path { fill: none }  #svg22 path[fill="none"], #svg22 circle[fill="none"], #svg22 polygon[fill="none"], #svg22 rect[fill="none"] { fill: none } </style><style type="text/css"> #svg22 .st0{fill:rgb(0, 0, 0);} </style><path class="st0" d="M85.78,98.797l-9.157-74.312l1.803-15.536c0.091-0.793-0.161-1.586-0.689-2.181 c-0.531-0.595-1.29-0.934-2.086-0.934H52.35c-0.796,0-1.557,0.339-2.086,0.934c-0.53,0.595-0.78,1.388-0.689,2.181l1.803,15.536 L42.22,98.797c-0.103,0.822,0.167,1.648,0.736,2.254l19.008,20.235c0.528,0.562,1.265,0.879,2.036,0.879s1.508-0.317,2.034-0.879 l19.01-20.235C85.611,100.445,85.883,99.619,85.78,98.797z M72.566,23.098H55.434l-1.517-13.074h20.166L72.566,23.098z"></path></g>
      </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Я попробую применить ваше решение. Посмотрим. что получится. Как минимум в нем есть одно бесспорное пореимущество - всего один элемент добавляем, а не как в моем решении)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так: https://jsfiddle.net/hk5t4t8v/318/

```
    <div class="container">

    <svg viewBox="0 0 128 128"; style="border-radius: 7%; width=128px; 
     height:128px">
    <rect  x="6.4" y="6.4" width="115.2" height="115.2"  style="stroke: rgb(0, 
    0, 0); fill: none; stroke-alignment: inside; stroke-width: 12.8" rx="7%" 
    ry="7%"></rect>
    <g transform="scale(0.6) translate(42.66666666666667, 42.66666666666667)">
    <style> #svg22 path, #svg22 circle, #svg22 polygon, #svg22 rect { fill: 
    rgb(0, 0, 0) } #svg22 defs &gt; path { fill: none }  #svg22 
    path[fill="none"], #svg22 circle[fill="none"], #svg22 polygon[fill="none"], 
    #svg22 rect[fill="none"] { fill: none } </style><style type="text/css"> 
    #svg22 .st0{fill:rgb(0, 0, 0);} </style><path class="st0" d="M85.78,98.797l-
    9.157-74.312l1.803-15.536c0.091-0.793-0.161-1.586-0.689-2.181 c-0.531-0.595-
    1.29-0.934-2.086-0.934H52.35c-0.796,0-1.557,0.339-2.086,0.934c-0.53,0.595-
    0.78,1.388-0.689,2.181l1.803,15.536 L42.22,98.797c-




 0.103,0.822,0.167,1.648,0.736,2.254l19.008,20.235c0.528,0.562,1.265,0.879,2.036,0.879s1.508-0.317,2.034-0.879 l19.01-20.235C85.611,100.445,85.883,99.619,85.78,98.797z M72.566,23.098H55.434l-1.517-13.074h20.166L72.566,23.098z"></path></g>
      </svg>
</div>



.container{
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
}

.svg {
  box-shadow: rgb(0, 0, 0) 0px 0px 8px 13px;
}
```

Comment: Все бы хорошо, но вы просто убрали тень у `svg`))). А она то мне нужна.

Comment: Да, полдня проковырялась, ничего не получается. ((

Comment: Так я 8 часов на это убил. Вроде бы такая мелочь, а неприятно.

Comment: Терпение и труд... Молодец! Хорошо получилось. )

Comment: Может быть, так: https://jsfiddle.net/hk5t4t8v/329/  ?

Comment: Неплохо, но есть 3 но: 1 - Вы убрали скругление у `rect`, а оно там нужно. 2 - Скругление у контейнера `.container` больше, чем у `rect` - это не правильно. 3 - не работает для скругления в `50%`.

Answer (score 1):

В итоге выкрутился следующим образом.

Конечно, не идеально. Вообще плохо. Но ничего другого в голову не пришло))

```css
.container,
.svg {
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}

.svg {
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0 5px rgb(0, 0, 0), rgb(0, 0, 0) 0px 0px 8px 13px;
}

.border {
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  left: -2px;
  right: -2px;
  bottom: -2px;
  border: 4px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="border" style="border-radius: 7%;"></div>
  <svg class="svg" style="border-radius: 7%;">
   <rect  x="6.4" y="6.4" width="115.2" height="115.2"  style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); fill: none; stroke-alignment: inside; stroke-width: 12.8" rx="7%" ry="7%"></rect>
    <g transform="scale(0.6) translate(42.66666666666667, 42.66666666666667)"><style> #svg22 path, #svg22 circle, #svg22 polygon, #svg22 rect { fill: rgb(0, 0, 0) } #svg22 defs &gt; path { fill: none }  #svg22 path[fill="none"], #svg22 circle[fill="none"], #svg22 polygon[fill="none"], #svg22 rect[fill="none"] { fill: none } </style><style type="text/css"> #svg22 .st0{fill:rgb(0, 0, 0);} </style><path class="st0" d="M85.78,98.797l-9.157-74.312l1.803-15.536c0.091-0.793-0.161-1.586-0.689-2.181 c-0.531-0.595-1.29-0.934-2.086-0.934H52.35c-0.796,0-1.557,0.339-2.086,0.934c-0.53,0.595-0.78,1.388-0.689,2.181l1.803,15.536 L42.22,98.797c-0.103,0.822,0.167,1.648,0.736,2.254l19.008,20.235c0.528,0.562,1.265,0.879,2.036,0.879s1.508-0.317,2.034-0.879 l19.01-20.235C85.611,100.445,85.883,99.619,85.78,98.797z M72.566,23.098H55.434l-1.517-13.074h20.166L72.566,23.098z"></path></g>
      </svg>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<div class="container">

  <svg class="svg" style="border-radius: 50%;">
   <rect  x="6.4" y="6.4" width="115.2" height="115.2"  style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); fill: none; stroke-alignment: inside; stroke-width: 12.8" rx="50%" ry="50%"></rect>
    <g transform="scale(0.6) translate(42.66666666666667, 42.66666666666667)"><style> #svg22 path, #svg22 circle, #svg22 polygon, #svg22 rect { fill: rgb(0, 0, 0) } #svg22 defs &gt; path { fill: none }  #svg22 path[fill="none"], #svg22 circle[fill="none"], #svg22 polygon[fill="none"], #svg22 rect[fill="none"] { fill: none } </style><style type="text/css"> #svg22 .st0{fill:rgb(0, 0, 0);} </style><path class="st0" d="M85.78,98.797l-9.157-74.312l1.803-15.536c0.091-0.793-0.161-1.586-0.689-2.181 c-0.531-0.595-1.29-0.934-2.086-0.934H52.35c-0.796,0-1.557,0.339-2.086,0.934c-0.53,0.595-0.78,1.388-0.689,2.181l1.803,15.536 L42.22,98.797c-0.103,0.822,0.167,1.648,0.736,2.254l19.008,20.235c0.528,0.562,1.265,0.879,2.036,0.879s1.508-0.317,2.034-0.879 l19.01-20.235C85.611,100.445,85.883,99.619,85.78,98.797z M72.566,23.098H55.434l-1.517-13.074h20.166L72.566,23.098z"></path></g>
     <div class="border" style="border-radius: 50%;"></div>
      </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Можно было бы через фильтры сделать тень, а затем увеличить её область действия

Comment: Если имеется ввиду фильтр тени для `rect` - то пробовал, ничего хорошего не получилось.